# what would cause x: and y: values to be off in the Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

a noob question here.

I have a very strange situation that's very puzzling to me.
I am setting up my labels and textfields in a prepareScreen method

example for Portrait:

```
titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(107,45,105,29);
```

and the same label in Landscape:

```
titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(187,0,105,29);
```

I got these values after I initially created the layout in the Interface Builder many versions and builds ago. So today, I wanted to change the layout slightly only to find the Interface Builder reporting very weird X: and Y: numbers for all objects.

For example for the titleLabel.frames mentioned above it shows:
X:159 and Y: 59 for Portrait
and
X:239 and Y: 14 for Landscape.

and when I manually move the label into the Top Left corner it shows X:52 and Y:14 values. For a different label, the difference is different. For some its off by X:5 and Y:8 and for some by X:67 and Y:15. Looks like the bigger the object, the bigger the difference.
What would cause the Interface Builder to behave like this ? What's happening here ? Any ideas ?

thank you!

Comment: Do you by chance accidentally have the anchor in IB changed to the bottom right corner?

Comment: whoa, it looks like this is it. the anchor was in the middle, but when I changed it to the top left corner I got the values I was looking for (used to have). you should make this an answer, so I can credit you with an answer. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the anchor that was set incorrectly. the credit goes to Allara and I will gladly change the answer to Allara's, once its created. I just don't want to leave this question opened and unanswered, since I already got what I was looking for.